# Consolidate duplicate clients and sales

Tags: sql, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a question and I can't come up with a good way to solve it, this is using SQLServer 2008R2.

I have 3 tables

```
Client, Invoice, Car
```

The client is duplicate n times, but each client has a ticket and one product.

So I am trying to consolidate the clients (with a unique identifier), now my question would be how to update the reference field on the product and ticket.

Example

```
**Client**

[Nombre]
      ,[Apellido_Paterno]
      ,[Apellido_Materno]
      ,[Sexo]
      ,[Estado_Civil]
      ,[Fecha_Nacimiento]
      ,[RFC]
      ,[Saludo]
      ,[Persona]
      ,[Razon_Social]
      ,[Direccion]
      ,[Colonia]
      ,[Municipio_Delegacion]
      ,[Estado]
      ,[Codigo_Postal]
      ,[Lada_Casa]
      ,[Telefono_Casa]
      ,[Ext_Telefono_Casa]
      ,[Lada_Oficina]
      ,[Telefono_Oficina]
      ,[Ext_Telefono_Oficina]
      ,[Telefono_Celular]
      ,[Email_Personal]
      ,[Vehiculo_Actual_Anterior]
      ,[Marca_Actual_Anterior]
      ,[AnioModelo_Actual_Anterior]
      ,[Color_Actual_Anterior]
      ,[Escolaridad]
      ,[Venta_Id]
      ,[Nombre1]
      ,[Nombre2]

**Invoice**

[Factura_Cliente]
      ,[Factura_Distribuidor]
      ,[Precio_Base_Vehiculo]
      ,[Precio_Accesorios]
      ,[Precio_Vehiculo_DeContado]
      ,[Descuento]
      ,[Incentivo_Calculado]
      ,[Fecha_Entrega_DelVehiculo]
      ,[Fecha_Factura_Cliente]
      ,[Clave_Distribuidor]
      ,[Seguro_Gratis]
      ,[Clave_Promocion]
      ,[Tipo_Venta]
      ,[Unidad_de_Intercambio]
      ,[Venta_Id]

**Car**

[Modelo]
      ,[Marca]
      ,[AnioModelo]
      ,[Basico]
      ,[Cabecera]
      ,[Version]
      ,[Color_Exterior]
      ,[Color_Interior]
      ,[VIN]
      ,[Motor]
      ,[Transmision]
      ,[Origen]
      ,[Basico_Linea_Modelo]
      ,[Venta_Id]
```

I can consolidate the clients, (even if they have discrepancies on their fields), but I can't find a effective solution for this.

Edit: The first column on client shows the duplicate, while the second is the id that match the ticket and product.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post a query? Does not matter if it does not work, is a starting point and maybe the error is easy to solve. If you post some sample data it would be even better to test and give you a better answer

Comment: I haven't done a query yet, I am trying to think on some ideas first I  can use a store procedure to recive the id and use a min agregation to pass the same client but this would need me to doit with a while or cursor.

Comment: Could you please post the actual table structures?

Comment: You can use this [SQL Fiddle demo code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3fc16) to post your table structures and sample data

Comment: @Andreas added the structure.

Comment: @Yaroslav to many '' for the tool you give me to work (still a lovely tool no less, thanks for the link).

Comment: To answer the question there is no need to post 1000 rows, enough with a pair of them, just a sample to see what are you dealing with. This helps to see your problem more clearly.

Comment: Maybe you have something [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44608)

Comment: @Yaroslav correct, I need to play a bit more with that tool, so any idea how to consolidate a single client to cars, and invoice?

Comment: Answer from Randy should fit your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would make two more tables.

one for new consolidated clients (with all the same fields as the normal client)
and a mapping table between the old client and the new client.

this mapping table should store the id of the old one, and which i it was mapped to as a new one.

from here its pretty easy. update the other tables with the new id based on its current old id in the map table..

Comment: While this is a good idea, the duplicates are up to 1,000 per client so far (still doing the bulk insert).